# How to paginate filtered data using ramda and vue

Tags: vue.js, pagination

I am trying to make an ecommerce listing page with left sidebar having different filters and right side having products using ramda and vue. I have 2 problems:

(1) I am trying to filter product price in the range of 1-100.

(2) I am unable to paginate filtered products.

Problem 1 : I am passing [0,1,2,3,4,....,99,100] and I am trying to filter 99 out of it using "includes()" but the code is unable to filter which in normal JS it should but I dont know why ramda.js filters only exact words or numbers.

Problem 2 : While the products are getting loaded, the pagination is working fine but when I filter, as I want to show 10 items per page; it just shows 10 items in the 1st page and discards all the other filtered items and thus there are no pages after the 1st page.

Problem 1 :

```js
return R.pipe(R.pluck('product_prices'), R.uniq)(products_list)
```

```js
return this.products_list.filter(
  prod => (prod.product_prices].some(val => this.filters.includes(val)) )
)
```

Problem 2 :

```js
if (this.currentPage >= this.totalPages) {
  this.currentPage = this.totalPages 
} 
var index = this.currentPage * this.itemsPerPage - this.itemsPerPage; 
return this.filteredProducts.slice(index, index + this.itemsPerPage);
```

Problem 1 : I want to filter prices from a range of prices using ramda and vue.

Problem 2 : After any filter is applied, I should be able to see all the filtered products paginated.

Comment: You might want to share some data.  I don't know where the `99` comes in.  It's not at all clear what you're talking about when you say "the code is unable to filter which in normal JS it should but I dont know why ramda.js filters only exact words or numbers."  Ramda's [`includes`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#includes) is reasonably well documented; are you trying to combine its array behavior with its string one?  Finally, in the future, please only include one question per SO post.  It's easy enough to make additional ones.

Comment: @scott I will try to find out solution to problem 1 myself by going through the "includes". Can u help me with problem no 2. I am unable to paginate the filtered products. If my filter has 15 products and im showing 10 products per page, the pagination shows only 10 and discards the rest 5.

Comment: I don't know much about Vue.  But at the very least, I think you should share some data.  The code you've supplied is presumably the body of a method in some object that contains properties such as `currentPage`, `totalPages`, `itemsPerPage`, and `filteredProducts`.  It looks as though it's designed to get one page worth of data.  And it looks as though it should work.  So what sort of inputs do you have, what sort of output are you expecting, and what are you getting instead?

Comment: @scott here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/amitavadeb/zb8m5acp/18/ If you filter "Bay Area", you can see that it has 2 products but the pagination is limiting itself to only 1 page. It should show 2 pages as there are 2 "Bay Area" products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
this.resultCount = (!this.activeFilters.length) ? this.products.length : this.activeFilters.length
```

You don't want to count the filters, but the filtered products.  Like this:

```
this.resultCount = (!this.activeFilters.length) ? this.products.length : this.filteredProducts.length
```

You can see it in [another Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/zqpgduxs/). But next time, please post your code here.  A Fiddle link is a fine extra, but everything relevant should also appear in the question.  The code you posted is not enough to demonstrate your problem.